# I am using swagger in Laravel. I want to hide the API document

Tags: laravel, authentication, swagger

I am using swagger in Laravel. I want to hide the API document. See it by signing in
-> login and view the document

Comment: Are you using l5-swagger? You can add login information in the config file.

Comment: yes I use it, I want requests to login when entering document, not requests